# Ansible XML Adding Nested Children Idempotently

Tags: xml, ansible, namespaces, idempotent

I am trying to remediate [V-222934](https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/DISA_STIG_Apache_Tomcat_Application_Server_9_v2r4_Middleware.audit:edb4a119040562eac753da241edd2900) (Additional information at Tomcat [Default Servlet Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html))

Starting with the `web.xml` file:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee                       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Much more in actual web.xml -->
</web-app>
```

I want to end with

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee                       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>readonly</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Much more in actual web.xml -->
</web-app>
```

I started with the following Ansible:

```ansible
    - name: "V-222934: DefaultServlet set to readonly for PUT and DELETE"
      community.general.xml:
        path: "{{ atl_product_installation_versioned }}/conf/web.xml"
        xpath: "/j:web-app/j:servlet/j:servlet-class[text()=\"org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet\"]"
        insertafter: yes
        add_children:
          - init-param:
            - param-name: readonly
            - param-value: true
        pretty_print: yes
        namespaces:
          j: http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
```

But that threw an error complaining about a list rather than bytes/unicode.

Switching to `input_type: xml` I get some success:

```ansible
    - name: "V-222934: DefaultServlet set to readonly for PUT and DELETE"
      community.general.xml:
        path: "{{ atl_product_installation_versioned }}/conf/web.xml"
        xpath: "/j:web-app/j:servlet/j:servlet-class[text()=\"org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet\"]"
        insertafter: yes
        input_type: xml
        add_children:
          - "<init-param><param-name>readonly</param-name><param-value>true</param-value></init-param>"
        pretty_print: yes
        namespaces:
          j: http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
```

Which works but is not indempotent.

My big/primary question is: how do I make this idempotent?

Moreover, in my actual file there are more than one `<servlet>`. A solution I can live with is to specify `/ns:servlet[1]`. However, I would like to target the one with the `<servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>`.

I have a minor question of: how can I get the yaml input type to work? (I think the code looks cleaner and makes more sense with that formatting.)

And lastly: I only know enough about namespaces to make the Ansible work. If someone has a cleaner/clearer way of writing the code, I am open to any improvements.

Comment: Most of what you posted immaterial.  All you want to do is to modify an XML file. Do you need to change the XML dynamically or just once?  If only once why do it in code?  All you are trying to do is to test if the xml file has the read only parameter and if it does not have the parameter add the read only parameter so you do not insert it multiple times.

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of Ansible to make a change just once? Yes, I want to correct the XML a single time, but this is being done over multiple systems and I can't afford the bookkeeping to keep track of whether I have run the script already or not. I am still learning Ansible and was hoping I could get some insight into better practices. Idempotency when manipulating XML seems especially troublesome. Party of the elegance of Ansible is for Ansible to make the check itself before implementing the change. But if I have to make the check myself, that is a solution I hadn't previously thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make your task idempotent, just construct a XPath expression that matches what you are looking to add. Then use that in the `xpath` attribute, along with the `state: present` – which can be omitted since it is the default of the parameter.

So with the task:

```yaml
- xml:
    path: web.xml
    xpath: >-
      /ns:web-app
      /ns:servlet[
      ns:servlet-class[text()="org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet"]
      ]
      /ns:init-param[
      ns:param-name[text()="readonly"]
      and ns:param-value[text()="true"]
      ]
    pretty_print: true
    namespaces:
      ns: http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
```

Your XML ends up being

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>readonly</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Much more in actual web.xml -->
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thank you! This Ansible is much clearer than mine. There is one little wrinkle. In my actual file there are more than one `<servlet>`. A solution I can live with is to specify `/ns:servlet[1]`. However, I would like to target the one with the `<servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>`. I think I can do this with the parent expression. However tries like `/ns:parent::servlet-class[text()=\"org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet\"]` or `/ns:servlet-class[text()=\"org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet\"]/ns:..` are throwing an error. Suggestion?

Comment: I do recognize in my above example I have uneccessarily/improperly escaped quotes. I have tried it with the proper usage of `text()="org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet"` and continue to get errors.

Comment: You'll have to describe the child of the servlet node to target at the servlet level of the expression. I adapted the XPath In the answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you! I was finally able to get back to this issue and your solution is exactly what I needed. Thank you for demonstrating you admirable Ansible/XML-fu